# Перегрузка оператора= для пользовательских классов в C++

Tags: c++, ооп, перегрузка-операторов

В общем ситуация такая:
Есть пользовательский класс Class в нем перегружаем оператор = и +
получаем следующее:

```
'''
ClassA Var{};

std::string Str = Var.get(); // Работает, get() есть в классе, возвращает string

std::string Str = Var + ""; // Работает благодаря перегрузке operator+
    
std::string Str{}; Var = Str; // Работает благодаря перегрузке operator=
'''
```

Но как сделать?

```
'''
std::string Str = Var; // ????????????
'''
```

Я, собственно, нашел этот вопрос в комментариях на одном из уроков Ravesli по С++([131 урок](https://ravesli.com/urok-131-peregruzka-operatorov-cherez-druzhestvennye-funktsii/))
И автор вроде сам же на него и ответил:

> Сам и нашёл. Как я мог это пропустить.
> operator str() const { return get() } // Например
> Теперь всё работает как надо.

Но я так и не понял, что он имел ввиду. Попытался разобраться сам, не получилось.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как именно перегрузить "=", чтобы этот код работал:
***std::string Str = Var;***
Или если кто-то понял мысль автора, поясните пожалуйста.
Заранее благодарю

Comment: Переопределить оператор приведения типа, например, `ClassA::operator string()`.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, а я голову ломал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь оператором приведения типа, например:

```
using namespace std;

class ClassA
{
    string var;
public:
    ClassA(const string& s):var(s){};

    operator string() const { return var; }
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    ClassA s("Hello");

    string q = s;

}
```

Попробуйте закомментировать

```
operator string() const { return var; }
```

и компиляция не пройдет...